# Extract records modified in different date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have this table called t1 with these fields: codLoan, codOp, codCau, action, and dateExec. Action field can be assumed three values: 'I' (Inserted), 'M' (Modified) or 'C' (Cancelled).

My records can be modified in different dates, so I can have two records with the same codLoan but with different value for dateExec.

I have to extract all the records that have the same codLoan and different Action (I or M) in different dateExec.

For instance:

```
codLoan=1
dateExec= '2018/08/08'
action='I'

codLoan=1
dateExec= '2018/08/08'
action='M'

codLoan=2
dateExec= '2018/08/07'
action='I'

codLoan=2
dateExec= '2018/08/08'
action='M'
```

---

Result: codLoan=2, dateExec= '2018/08/08'

---

I tried this query, but it extracts all the records with Action='I' and Action='M'.

```
select codLoan, dateExec
from t1
where Action in ('I','M');
```

How can I fix my code?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 
              from table t1 
              where t1.codLoan = t.codLoan and 
                    t1.dateExec <> t.dateExec and 
                    t1.action <> t.action
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a join:

```
select b.*
from mytable a
join mytable b on b.codLoan = a.codLoan
    and b.dateExec > a.dateExec
    and b.action != a.action
    and b.action in ('I','M')
where a.action in ('I','M')
```

This returns the *last* action and date.

Comment: [This appears to be working](http://rextester.com/ANA11897).  I couldn't figure it out, so I gave up, but you may use my demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table
(
    codLoan  int,
    dateExec date,
    [action] char(1)
);

insert into @t values
(1, '2018-08-08', 'I'),
(1, '2018-08-08', 'M'),
(2, '2018-08-07', 'I'),
(2, '2018-08-08', 'M');

with diff as
(
    select x.*
    from
    (
        select
            *,
            cnt1 = count(*) over (partition by codLoan, dateExec
                                  order by codLoan) ,
            cnt2 = count(*) over (partition by codLoan, [action], dateExec
                                  order by codLoan),
            rnum = row_number() over (partition by codLoan
                                      order by dateExec desc)
        from @t
    ) x
    where cnt1 = cnt2 
)
select codLoan, dateExec
from diff
where rnum = 1
order by codLoan, dateExec;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another option

```
select codLoan
     , dateExec = min(dateExec)
from t1
where Action in ('I','M')
Group By codLoan
Having min(dateExec)<>max(dateExec)
```